# GDI+ and Multi-Threading

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, gdi+

Following all information I found, GDI+ is capable to be used in a muli-threaded way, with just the restriction that a GDI+ object must not be used from several threads at the same time.

I have the problem of sporadic crashed of two threads in my C++ MFC Windows application (one cares for the splash window while startup, the other is the main thread doing some initialization stuff). The crashes are not reproducible, but have one thing in common: At least one of these both threads is in a GDI+ operation in the moment the program is stopped in the debugger.

Does anyone out here know something about GDI+ threading?

Comment: To my knowledge, GDI+ uses the Windows Imaging Component internally. WIC is based on COM. COM has strict threading rules. I'm guessing that `GdiplusStartup` and `GdiplusShutdown` initialize COM on the calling thread. If my guess is accurate, you cannot call GDI+ functions on arbitrary threads.

Comment: It turns out, I guessed wrong. There's no call to `CoInitialize[Ex]` in `GdiplusStartup`. Still, GDI+ objects frequently own GDI objects. If this happens to be a device context, you subscribe to [subtle thread affinity rules](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051011-10/?p=33823).

Comment: As I understood GdiPlusStartup is to be called once for all threads. And I definitively don't access any DC or GDI+ object from both threads (as they are both associated to different windows).

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use the "double buffer" mechanism to create 2 [memory DC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/memory-device-contexts)s for each map, use one by one. That is to say, the main window reads the memory DC A for display while the background thread draws on the memory DC B, and informs the main thread when the drawing is completed. After the main thread is notified, A and B are exchanged (B is displayed, and A is the object of the next background thread operation).

About [GdiplusStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusinit/nf-gdiplusinit-gdiplusstartup#remarks):

> You can call GdiplusStartup on one thread and call GdiplusShutdown on
>   another thread as long as you delete all of your GDI+ objects (or have
>   them go out of scope) before you call GdiplusShutdown.

The document also includes some other usage on it.
It also mentions how to use dynamic data exchange (DDE) with GDI+:

> If you want to initialize GDI+ for your application (by calling
>   GdiplusStartup in your InitInstance function), you have to suppress
>   the GDI+ background thread.

Comment: GDI objects are not the same thing as GDI+ though.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out, and I still recommend OP to use "double buffer".

Comment: This refers to multi-threaded GDI drawing. I think the multi-threading capabilities of GDI are quite clear (as long as I use one DC or one GDI object only from one thread, it's working), but my question is still about issues with GDI+.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT: Why should I suppress the GDI+ background thread?

Comment: @nic: This only applies, if you are using both `CWinApp` and DDE (it's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/special-cwinapp-services)). [If you suppress GDI+ background thread, then you are expected to pump messages yourself](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191029-00/?p=103033) goes into more details about your liabilities, *if* you decide to suppress GDI+' background thread.

Comment: So there's no reason for suppressing the GDI+ background thread.

Comment: As obviously GDI+ causes multi-threading problems under my conditions I implemented a workaround fixing these sporadic access violations. I shifted all GDI+ operations into the main thread. This succeeded because updates on the splash window are triggered from the main thread; there's no WM_PAINT handler because I'm using a layered window. The only operation occurring independent from the main thread is a visual fading-in of my progress bar, which I now implemented only with GDI operations, now using AlphaBlend().